# problema con web sockets

Tags: nodejs, angular, socket.io, sequelize.js

como puedo  extraer una data de mi bd en mysql y luego enviar ese objeto mediante web sockets estoy tratando de enviar notificaciones
estoy haciendo una api restfull pero necesito enviar notificaciones en tiempo real  cuando activen las notificaciones mediante mi api  estoy llamando a un servicio en mi backend que deberia retornar el objeto con los datos de la bd pero cuando lo envio con el sockent.emit no llena nada una ayuda porfavor

> estoy usando sequelize como orm para la bd

```js
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:4200",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      credentials: true
  },
  allowEIO3: true
});
var notifications = require('./services/getNotifications').getNotifys();
  
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  const socketId = socket.id;
  console.log('se ha conectado el id: ' + '-----------' + socketId);
  //notification
  socket.emit('Notifications',notifications);
});
//rutas
module.exports = {server,io};
```

aqui es donde tengo mi conection
y este es el servicio que llamo

```js
var { Product_Notification,Product } = require('../models/index');

exports.getNotifys = async function(){

    const activeNotifications = await Product_Notification.findAll({
      where: { status:true }, 
      attributes:["id","value_to_report"],
      include:{
        association: "item",
        attributes:["id","name","product_quantity","product_code"],
        where:{active_notification: true}
      }
    }).catch(err =>{ return err});

    if(activeNotifications && activeNotifications.length > 0) return activeNotifications;
    else return message = "any notification active yet";
}
```

esto es lo que recibo en mi fron de angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de esta manera es que  conecto el socket con el front en angular

```js
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotifiSocketService extends Socket{
  outEven: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  callBack: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
  ) {
    super({ url: 'http://localhost:5000', options: {}});
    this.listen();
  } 
  listen = () =>{
    this.ioSocket.on('Notifications',(res: any) => this.callBack.emit(res));
  }
  
}
```

servicio que  llamo en mi  componente navbar :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck,OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  subscriptions:Subscription []=[];
  public notifications:Notification[] = [];
  public _notifications!:number
  public user:any;
  public msg:string = 'hola';
  public pinga:any;
  constructor(
    private socket: NotifiSocketService,
    private _userService:UserService,
    private _notificationService:NotificationService,
  ) {
    this.user = _userService.getIdentity();
    socket.callBack.subscribe( res =>{
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

agradeceria la ayuda soy bastante nuevo con sockets apenas lo estoy usando

si me pueden guiar de como hcaer el codigo mas escalable lo agradeceria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estas enviando nada en el emit de tu socket:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  const socketId = socket.id;
  console.log('se ha conectado el id: ' + '-----------' + socketId);
  //Deberia ser un texto o un objeto.
  socket.emit('Notifications', "Una notificacion!!!");
});
```

## [Emitiendo eventos](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/#basic-emit)

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //Puede ser tu json...
  socket.emit("hello", "world");
});

// client-side
socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // world
});
```

### Edición

No debes mandar el callback, debes mandar el objeto:

```
socket.emit('Notifications',notifications);
```

### Edicion 2 - Arreglos vacios son verdaderos

Esta es la validación que haces.

```js
let arregloVacio = []


if(arregloVacio) alert('El arreglo no esta vacio')
else alert('El arreglo esta vacio')
```

Debes validar la longitud del arreglo:

```js
let arregloVacio = []


if(arregloVacio.length) alert('El arreglo no esta vacio')
else alert('El arreglo esta vacio')
```

Comment: var notifications = require('./services/getNotifications').getNotifys(); esto envio esta mas arriba

Comment: Estas enviando un callback en el emit. El emit no puede enviar callbacks, eso es para escuchar con `on`. Edito mi pregunta.

Comment: es que ya lo hice tambien y solo devuelve el objeto vacio no se si es porque es un funcion asyncrona con sequelise o que pueda ser

Comment: Y estas seguro que la consulta no esta devolviendo un valor vacio? La validación que haces dejaría pasar un arreglo vacío. Esta linea: `if(activeNotifications)` siempre será verdadero por que el query que haces con `findAll`, si no encuentra nada, devuelve un arreglo vacio.

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo de lo comentado. Mira la segunda edición.

Comment: si si ya lo hice sigue arrojando un objeto vacio envie el objeto por consola del backend y lo que dice es que es un promise use el Promise.resolve then y ya envia los datos ese era el error

Comment: Excelente. Que bueno que lo resolviste.

Comment: sabes como al momento de la coneccion puedo enviar un string   ? quiero enviar un token para validad la sesion

Comment: Usa el socket.emit('token', "untoken"). En cuanto alguien se conecte, y en tu front este escuchando por "token", lo recibira. Lo único es que al identificador del socket tienes que agregarle un identificador único, por el ejemplo, el id del usuario. Para que no lo escuchen todos.

Comment: muchas gracias :)